# ansible jira module "msg": "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: ansible, jira

Im trying to use the jira module in a number of plays.
In all cases, reguardless of what action I use I always get "msg": "No JSON object could be decoded"

for example
- name: task search get all issues with uri module

```
  jira:
    uri: "https://{{ jira_server }}"
    username: '{{ jira_user }}'
    password: '{{ jira_pass }}'
    project: "{{ jira_project }}"
    operation: search
    jql: "summary~{{ jira_summary }}"
    description: "{{ jira_description }}”
```

The variables seem to be ok if I use debug and I can cut paste into a curl command and have them execute correctly for a result
Also If I use the same vars with the uri module I can get it to work

With the jira module execution results in rhe following error

```
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_jira_payload_tyHCeM/ansible_jira_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/jira.py", line 529, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_jira_payload_tyHCeM/ansible_jira_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/jira.py", line 416, in search
  File "/tmp/ansible_jira_payload_tyHCeM/ansible_jira_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/jira.py", line 343, in get
  File "/tmp/ansible_jira_payload_tyHCeM/ansible_jira_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/jira.py", line 312, in request
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "assignee": null,
            "comment": null,
            "description": null,
            "fields": {},
            "inwardissue": null,
            "issue": null,
            "issuetype": null,
            "jql": "summary~AWS Non-Prod instances in breach of Cloud Patching Compliance Rules",
            "linktype": null,
            "maxresults": null,
            "operation": "search",
            "outwardissue": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "project": "MEST",
            "status": null,
            "summary": null,
            "timeout": 10.0,
            "uri": "https://jira-host-name",
            "username": "srv_splats_ansible",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

any ideas would be fantastic
thanks